# Development of stand-alone javascript lib

Tags: javascript, ide

I have a need for a calculation lib that I want to run on either client or server.  I'd like to do it like a ruby gem or java bean, with a directory of files that are packaged for deployment, as well as set of tests that of course are not deployed, but are executed in the IDE.

Does anyone have any tips or links to article about this?  It seems that most tutorials or advice is geared toward developing for the browser or, (more recently) SSJS frameworks like Node.

Also, are there any IDEs that have template projects that help with this?  They seem to generally set up web apps.

Answer (score 1):

The [CommonJS specification](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/) with its module and unit testing system is a step in that direction (and the only cross JavaScript engine approach I know of so far). I only used V8 (NodeJS) as an actual [implementation](http://www.commonjs.org/impl/) so far, so I don't know how well the browser based ones work.

Comment: I've noticed CommonJS before, but I don't think its what I'm looking for i.e. a non-runtime specific development environment

Comment: Well it's not really a development environment but more a set of non-runtime specific standards - which I think might be more basic than the environment and IDE that a library was implemented with...